# Sphinx как добавить дефис в слова?

Tags: php, ubuntu, sphinx

Настроил сфинкс все хорошо, ищет быстро!
Я его настраивал для интернет магазина комп техники, там очень много нужно словоформ
я создал файлик с фразами

```
16гб > 16gb
16 гб > 16gb
16 gb > 16gb
Intel > интел
AMD > амд
```

Тоже все хорошо, но мне надо искать по таким словам с дефисом, типа:

```
DDR-3
DDR-III
TK-1140
```

Вобщем, я нашел есть такой параметр

```
blend_chars = -, &
```

Вот мой конфиг

```
path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/xxxx
docinfo         = extern
mlock           = 0
wordforms       = /home/xxxx/pokupki/public_html/word.txt
html_strip      = 1
min_word_len        = 2
index_exact_words   = 1
morphology          = stem_ru
charset_type        = utf-8
```

Все работает, но как только я пытаюсь добавить параметр для дефиса, у меня перестают работать словоформы - wordforms

Что делать?
Как заставить искать по словам с дефисом? и чтобы работали словоформы
мне предстоит их еще дополнять очень и оч много

Answer (score 1):

Настройте [`charset_table`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-charset-table.html). Вот мой конфиг:

```
charset_table       = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F,  U+0401->U+0435, U+0451->U+0435,\
                 U+AD, U+002D,U+002D, U+2012, U+2013, U+2014, U+2015, U+2011, U+2010, -, _
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DDR-III=>DDR3
DDR-three=>DDR3
-------------------
blend_chars = U+2d
```

Comment: В Markdown горизонтальная черта — это разметка для заголовка. Поправил на код, так нормально выглядит. Минус не мой, если что. )